# Syntax Highlight in Winedt

Tags: tikz-pgf, editors, highlighting, winedt

I am using `Winedt 7.1` and learning `TikZ` and I am thinking about to add the commands to the `keyword.ini`, in the help they mentioned, adding to many keywords may affect the performance. Is there a possibility that the `TikZ-Commands` are only highlighted inside a tikzpicture environment?

Answer (score 5):

### Update (2017-02-14)

WinEdt version 10.2 implements a new feature: environment-sensitive modes.

This means that you have the chance to define highlighting properties specific to some environments only.

Thank to this new feature, a `TikZ` mode has been implemented, with an highlighting scheme borrowed from the one used in the `pgf` manual. Here's it in action:

[image]

This is an example which defines an "highlight switch" for the `tikzpicture` environment in the configuration file `Switches.ini`:

```
SWITCH="\begin{tikzpicture} .. \end{tikzpicture}"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER="TeX|AUX"
  SET_LOCAL_MODE="*:TikZ"
  START="\"
  STOP="\"
  HIGHLIGHT_START=0
  STEP_OVER_STOP=1
  HIGHLIGHT_STOP=0
  SCOPE=4
  DOMINANT_PRIORITY=0
  STRICT_PRIORITY=0
  PRIORITY=5
  INDENTED=1
  BOLN_ONLY=0
  CASE_SENSITIVE=1
  START1_TRIGGER=""
  START2_TRIGGER="begin{tikzpicture}"
  STOP1_TRIGGER=""
  STOP2_TRIGGER="end{tikzpicture}"
    TEXT_COLOR="sclWindowText"
    DEFAULT_FONT=1
  CUSTOM_BACKGROUND=1
  GRADIENT_BACKGROUND=256
  TRANSPARENT=128
  GRADIENT_COLOR="xclEnvBkLeftGradient"
  BACKGROUND_COLOR="xclEnvBk"
  RELATIVE_RIGHT_MARGIN=1
  RIGHT_MARGIN=0
  INDENTED_LEFT_MARGIN=1
  LEFT_MARGIN=2
```

Note the line

```
  SET_LOCAL_MODE="*:TikZ"
```

which enters the `TikZ` mode.

Now, if you want to define your own keywords to be highlighted only inside these kind of environments, all you have to do is to define a "keyword group" in the configuration file "Keywords.ini" like this:

```
KEYWORD_GROUP="My TikZ Keywords"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER="TikZ"
  BEFORE="\ (single)"
  AFTER="~Alpha@"
  BOLN_NOT_OK=1
  EOLN_NOT_OK=0
  HIGHLIGHT_START=1
  STRICT_PRIORITY=0
  PRIORITY=6
  CASE_SENSITIVE=1
    TEXT_COLOR="kwcTikZKeywords"
    DEFAULT_FONT=1
LIST="END_LIST"
<my list of keywords>
END_LIST
```

Note the line

```
  MODE_FILTER="TikZ"
```

which means that these keywords are highlighted only when inside the `TikZ` mode.

---

### Original answer

As far as I know, it is not possible to add environment-specific keywords in WinEdt.

Anyway, unless you have a very old computer and you add thousands of keywords, you will not see any particular slowdown in WinEdt's performance.